# need help to configure postfix / dovecot + SSL for ports 993, 465 + virtual mail/accounts from file + CRAM-MD5 authentification

Tags: ssl, postfix, dovecot

I have some issues in my configs to have an full functional mailserver with CRAM-MD5 authentification for only port 993 and 465. Plz help me and others to get an right config file struct for ubuntu servers and for the future if someone are seaching for full configs like that. I have big problems to understand the right combination of the parameters to get the right result. I will update and write the right working config each time you write some useful. Hope that will helps also other, because it's not easy to figure out how to set the right parameters for so much different stuff =(

btw. plz help me to create an relative secure config and tell me if i have to change some chmod or chown security settings
thx and i hope that file will help a lot of users in the future

thats the main problems:

Problem 1: to connect to imaps over outlook and without sending plain passwords

```
1st: i create an CRAM-MD5 Hash
doveadm pw -s CRAM-MD5
  THE SECRET PASSWORD
output: {CRAM-MD5}aaaabbbbcccccddddeeeeffffggggghhhhiiiiijjjjjkkkkklllllmmmmmnnnnn
which i use under: /etc/dovecot/users

2nd: if i connect over openssl s_client -connect localhost:993 it works, but not over outlook and only as plain password
openssl s_client -connect localhost:993
A login office@MY_DOMAIN.COM "THE SECRET PASSWORD"
output: A OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABL ....]

how to solve that without plain passwords over the cfgs and login?
```

Problem 2: cant connect successfuly over openssl s_client -connect localhost:465

```
1st:
  openssl s_client -connect localhost:465
  AUTH CRAM-MD5
  output: NEEDED_CHALLANGE_BASE64_HASH_VALUE_FOR_PASSWORD 
2nd: 
  apt install sasl2-bin
  gen-auth CRAM-MD5
    Username: office@MY_DOMAIN.COM
    password: THE SECRET PASSWORD
    challange: NEEDED_CHALLANGE_BASE64_HASH_VALUE_FOR_PASSWORD
  output: BASE64_HAHS_VALUE_FOR_LOGIN
3rd:
  openssl s_client -connect localhost:465
  AUTH CRAM-MD5
  BASE64_HAHS_VALUE_FOR_LOGIN
  output: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: ...
  output-mail.log: warning: localhost[127.0.0.1]: SASL CRAM-MD5 authentication failed: ...

what do i wrong?
```

Problem 3: openssl s_client -connect localhost:993 errors, which i dont have for port 465 and 443. It's the same apache SSL which i want to use for the mail server. Mailserver == webserver

```
conclusion:
  error 1: Can't use SSL_get_servername 
    I know. Thats because i am logged in as localhost and not over MY_DOMAIN.COM
  error 2: verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
    also if i try with 
    openssl s_client -CAfile /var/www/security/SSL/MY_DOMAIN.ca-bundle -crlf -connect localhost:993
    output: 
      verify error:num=2:unable to get issuer certificate
      SSL handshake has read 2063 bytes and written 373 bytes
      Verification error: unable to get issuer certificate

full but shorted output: openssl s_client -connect localhost:993
CONNECTED(00000003)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=0 CN = MY_DOMAIN.COM
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = MY_DOMAIN.COM
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = MY_DOMAIN.COM
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
0 s:CN = MY_DOMAIN.COM
  i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
  a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
  v:NotBefore: May  7 00:00:00 2023 GMT; NotAfter: Aug 15 23:59:59 2023 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = MY_DOMAIN.COM
issuer=C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2063 bytes and written 373 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 
    ...
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 
    ...
    Start Time: 1684318538
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE
```

### Postfix

Folder: /etc/postfix/

[root:root - rights:655] main.cf

```
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 3.6
mydomain = MY_DOMAIN.COM
myhostname = web-p3.$mydomain
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, mail.$mydomain, web-p3.$mydomain, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
# old settings
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
relayhost =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
# Virtual Domain Einstellungen
virtual_mailbox_domains = $mydomain
#virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_domains
#virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
#virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-mailbox
#virtual_alias_domains =
#virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
# SSL Einstellungen
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /var/www/ssl/MY_DOMAIN.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /var/www/ssl/MY_DOMAIN.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /var/www/ssl/MY_DOMAIN.ca-bundle
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:office@$mydomain:999999999-000000000000-9999999
#smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
#smtpd_sasl_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
#smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous,noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes 
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = login
```

[root:root - rights:644] master.cf

```
smtps      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRXhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FRX user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
```

[root:root - rights:644] virtual-mailbox

```
office@MY_DOMAIN.COM  MY_DOMAIN.COM/office/Maildir/
```

Original files! No changes

```
[root:root - rights:644] main.cf.proto
[root:root - rights:644] master.cf.proto
```

### Dovecot

#Folder: /etc/dovecot/

[root:root - rights:644] dovecot.conf

```
!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol
protocols = imap lmtp
listen = *, ::
dict {}
!include conf.d/*.conf
!include_try local.conf
```

[root:dovecot - rights:640] dovecot-dict-auth.conf.ext

```
default_pass_scheme = CRAM-MD5
#default_pass_scheme = MD5
iterate_prefix = userdb/
key passdb {
  key = passdb/%u
  format = json
}
key userdb {
  key = userdb/%u
  format = json
}
key quota {
  key = userdb/%u/quota
  default_value = 100M
}
passdb_objects = passdb
userdb_objects = userdb
userdb_fields {
  quota_rule = *:storage=%{dict:quota}
  mail = maildir:%{dict:userdb.home}/Maildir
}
```

[root:dovecot - rights:640] dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext

```
map {
  pattern = priv/quota/storage
  table = quota
  username_field = username
  value_field = bytes
}
map {
  pattern = priv/quota/messages
  table = quota
  username_field = username
  value_field = messages
}
map {
  pattern = shared/expire/$user/$mailbox
  table = expires
  value_field = expire_stamp
  fields {
    username = $user
    mailbox = $mailbox
  }
}
```

[root:root - rights:644] users

```
office@MY_DOMAIN.COM:{CRAM-MD5}aaaabbbbcccccddddeeeeffffggggghhhhiiiiijjjjjkkkkklllllmmmmmnnnnn
```

[root:dovecot - rights:640] dovecot-sql.conf.ext

```
# empty
```

#Folder: /etc/dovecot/conf.d/

[root:root - rights:644] 10-auth.conf

```
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
auth_username_format = %Lu
auth_master_user_separator = *
auth_mechanisms = cram-md5 plain login
#!include auth-system.conf.ext
!include auth-passwdfile.conf.ext
!include auth-static.conf.ext
```

[root:root - rights:644] 10-director.conf

```
service director {
  unix_listener login/director {}
  fifo_listener login/proxy-notify {}
  unix_listener director-userdb {}
  inet_listener {}
}
service imap-login {}
service pop3-login {}
service submission-login {}
protocol lmtp {}
```

[root:root - rights:644] 10-logging.conf

```
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-info.log
plugin {}
```

[root:root - rights:644] 10-mail.conf

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
}
mail_privileged_group = mail
protocol !indexer-worker {}
mail_uid = vmail
mail_gid = vmail
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
```

[root:root - rights:644] 10-master.conf

```
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {}
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {}
  inet_listener pop3s {}
}
service submission-login {
  inet_listener submission {}
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener lmtp {}
}
service imap {}
service pop3 {}
service submission {}
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-userdb {}
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }
}
service auth-worker {}
service dict {
  unix_listener dict {}
}
```

[root:root - rights:644] 10-ssl.conf

```
ssl = yes
ssl_cert = </var/www/ssl/MY_DOMAIN.crt
ssl_key = </var/www/ssl/MY_DOMAIN.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = </usr/share/dovecot/dh.pem
```

[root:root - rights:644] 10-tcpwrapper.conf

```
#empty
```

[root:root - rights:644] 15-lda.conf

```
protocol lda {}
```

[root:root - rights:644] 15-mailboxes.conf

```
namespace inbox {
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
}
```

[root:root - rights:644] 20-imap.conf

```
protocol imap {}
```

[root:root - rights:644] 20-lmtp.conf

```
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
}
plugin {
  sieve = /var/vmail/%d/%n/.sieve
  sieve_dir = /var/vmail/%d/%n/sieve
  sieve_global_dir = /var/vmail/sieve/global/
}
```

[root:root - rights:644] 90-acl.conf

```
plugin {}
plugin {}
```

[root:root - rights:644] 90-plugin.conf

```
plugin {}
```

[root:root - rights:644] 90-quota.conf

```
plugin {}
plugin {}
plugin {}
plugin {}
```

[root:root - rights:644] auth-checkpassword.conf.ext

```
passdb {
  driver = checkpassword
  args = /usr/bin/checkpassword
}
userdb {
  driver = prefetch
}
```

[root:root - rights:644] auth-deny.conf.ext

```
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  deny = yes
  args = /etc/dovecot/deny-users
}
```

[root:root - rights:644] auth-dict.conf.ext

```
passdb {
  driver = dict
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-auth.conf.ext
}
userdb {
  driver = dict
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-auth.conf.ext
}
```

[root:root - rights:644] auth-master.conf.ext

```
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  master = yes
  args = /etc/dovecot/master-users
  pass = yes
}
```

[root:root - rights:644] auth-passwdfile.conf.ext

```
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = scheme=CRAM-MD5 username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/users
}
userdb {
  driver = static
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
}
```

[root:root - rights:644] auth-sql.conf.ext

```
passdb {
  driver = sql
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}
userdb {
  driver = sql
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}
```

[root:root - rights:644] auth-static.conf.ext

```
# empty
```

[root:root - rights:644] auth-system.conf.ext

```
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```